# Creating script to add static routes to different sub-interfaces on file /etc/network/interfaces using sed

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

I'm in charge of 30 backbone servers that are configured with sub-interfaces to connect to different VLANs via a single trunk. The servers use Ubuntu 18.04 and we use static routing to connect to remotes at customer premises.

Whenever there is a new remote location, we need to manually add static routes to this location on all the servers which is very in efficient, that's why I was looking into creating a bash script to add the new static route of the new location to the /etc/network/interfaces file in the servers.

Unfortunately I have no experience on writing bash scripts, but after doing some research I came out with a basic idea on how to solve this problem.

The /etc/network/interfaces file looks like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Management Interface
auto ens160
 iface ens160 inet static
  address 172.20.144.250
  netmask 255.255.255.128
  gateway 172.20.144.129

# MTNMGT Interface
auto ens256
 iface ens256 inet static
  address 10.112.105.60
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  up route add -net 10.112.105.0 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 10.112.105.1
  #Remote Location
  up route add -net 10.172.15.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.112.105.1

# MONITORING Interface
auto ens224
iface ens224 inet static
        address 10.112.106.124
        netmask 255.255.255.192
        up route add -net 10.112.106.64 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 10.112.106.65
        #Remote Location
        up route add -net 10.172.15.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.112.106.65
```

All I want to do is to add the command:

```
up route add -net 10.172.15.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.112.106.65
```

to the MTNMGT and MONITORING interface sections of the /etc/network interfaces file.

Looks to me that `sed` can do the job, as we can insert lines before or after a particular pattern, in this case, it could be the Interface's name:

`$ sed -i '/MONITORING/a up route add -net X.X.X.X netmask X.X.X.X gw X.X.X.X '`

That would insert the static route below the interface description #MONITORING Interface. However I want to insert it were the static routes are located, that is five rows below the interface description and that's my question:

Is there any way to use some kind of "AND" operator to indicate that I want to insert the new line below the Interface description AND five rows below?

Any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: `n` reads the `n`ext line. maybe `/MONITOR/{n;n;n;n;n;a .... ; } ` will do what you need. But `awk` is really be a better tool for making this sort of modification, it will easily allow you to extend your modifying tool to allow for parameterizing your process. Good luck.

Comment: instead of "editing" this file, which is error prone, just create 2 files and source them. any time you add a new location, and you add a line to each file. see:https://askubuntu.com/questions/323566/separate-etc-network-interfaces-file

Answer (score 0):

So if you tidy up the `interfaces` file to

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Management Interface
auto ens160
 iface ens160 inet static
  address 172.20.144.250
  netmask 255.255.255.128
  gateway 172.20.144.129

# MTNMGT Interface
auto ens256
 iface ens256 inet static
  address 10.112.105.60
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  up route add -net 10.112.105.0 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 10.112.105.1
  #Remote Location

# MONITORING Interface
auto ens224
 iface ens224 inet static
  address 10.112.106.124
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  up route add -net 10.112.106.64 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 10.112.106.65
  #Remote Location
```

then this will do this job:

```
$ cat add_route.sed
/^# \(MONITORING\|MTNMGT\)/!b
:loop
n
/^$/i\
  up route add -net 10.172.15.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.112.105.1
$a\
  up route add -net 10.172.15.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.112.105.1
/^$/!b loop
$ sed -f add_route.sed interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Management Interface
auto ens160
 iface ens160 inet static
  address 172.20.144.250
  netmask 255.255.255.128
  gateway 172.20.144.129

# MTNMGT Interface
auto ens256
 iface ens256 inet static
  address 10.112.105.60
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  up route add -net 10.112.105.0 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 10.112.105.1
  #Remote Location
  up route add -net 10.172.15.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.112.105.1

# MONITORING Interface
auto ens224
 iface ens224 inet static
  address 10.112.106.124
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  up route add -net 10.112.106.64 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 10.112.106.65
  #Remote Location
  up route add -net 10.172.15.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.112.105.1
```

The `sed` script spots `# MONITORING` or `# MTNMGT` and then looks for a section break empty line or the last line and inserts or appends a line accordingly.

A much simpler approach would be to spot the `#Remote Location` comment:

```
$ cat add_route2.sed
/#Remote Location/a\
  up route add -net 10.172.15.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.112.105.1
$ sed -f add_route2.sed interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Management Interface
auto ens160
 iface ens160 inet static
  address 172.20.144.250
  netmask 255.255.255.128
  gateway 172.20.144.129

# MTNMGT Interface
auto ens256
 iface ens256 inet static
  address 10.112.105.60
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  up route add -net 10.112.105.0 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 10.112.105.1
  #Remote Location
  up route add -net 10.172.15.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.112.105.1

# MONITORING Interface
auto ens224
 iface ens224 inet static
  address 10.112.106.124
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  up route add -net 10.112.106.64 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 10.112.106.65
  #Remote Location
  up route add -net 10.172.15.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.112.105.1
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Thanks Jon, I guess this solves the problem.